# next 13 server side function fetching stale data from the sanity v3

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, sanity

I am building a blog website using next 13 with sanity v3 at the backend. The data next 13 is fetching from the sanity is stale.

**I have unpublished 1 documents from the sanity**

[document I, have unpublished from sanity studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6XGV.png)

**But my frontend is still rendering 3 documents**
[frontend still rendering 3 documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1j8Y.png)

Whenever I publish a new blog, or unpublish a blog, The change is not reflected in the data that is fetched by next13. Next 13 fetches old stale data. Data is not renewed event after I hard refresh it.
I am really confused as why is it happening. and how to fix it.

**I have tried a lot of solutions**
1.I have tried switching CDN.
2.using revalidate.
3.storing no-cache & fetch on every request.

**The sanity client code is**

```
import ImageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";

const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID
const dataset = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATABASE
const apiVersion = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_VERSION
const token = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN

export const client = createClient({
    projectId,
    dataset,
    apiVersion,
    useCdn: false,
    token
})

const builder = ImageUrlBuilder(client)

export function urlFor(source) {
    return builder.image(source)
  }
```

**The code I, am using to fetch the sanity data in next13 is**

```
import { client, urlFor } from '@/lib/sanity.client'
import { groq } from 'next-sanity'
import BlogList from '../components/BlogList'
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator'
import { Premium } from '../components/Premium'
import Tags from '../components/Tags'

const postQuery = groq`*[_type == "post"]{
  ...,
  description,
  author->,
  categories[]->
} | order(_createdAt desc)`


export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await client.fetch(postQuery)

  console.log(posts)
  return (
    <main className="flex justify-between w-11/12 m-auto">
      <BlogList data={posts}/>
        <Separator className='w-0.5 opacity-70 min-h-screen'/>
      <div className="w-3/12 flex flex-col items-center">
        <Premium/>
        <Tags/>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

**I have tried a lot of solutions**
1.I have tried switching CDN.
2.using revalidate.
3.storing no-cache & fetch on every request.

I am expecting that the next13 fetches realtime, updated data every second.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I noticed that when I changed the configuration of apiversion, it took about 400ms to fetch the data, and a cached JSON file was created in the `/next/cache/fetch-cache` directory. However, even after using the same apiversion, the fetched result remained stale data, and subsequent fetches took only 1ms without creating a cached file. This behavior indicated some form of caching in place, with the apiversion of the configuration being a key factor.

**Solution**: To bypass caching and ensure that I always fetch the latest data, I added the `{ cache: 'no-store' }` option to the `client.fetch` method:

```
export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await client.fetch(postQuery, undefined, { cache: 'no-store' });
  // ...
}
```

I hope this works well for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be something to do with the caching in next js. Have you tried adding the following piece of code to the top of your page / component file:

```
export const revalidate = 10
```

This will force the data revalidation every 10 seconds.

This is mentioned in the Next docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

Cheers
Conor

Answer (score 0):

I intended to post this as a comment, but due to insufficient reputation, I'm sharing it as an answer. Please understand that this might not be the solution you're searching for; I merely want to share my findings and experiences.

I faced the same problem. To check if the problem was with my fetching query, I tested it in Sanity Studio using the 'vision' tool. There, the fetch function worked as expected, fetching the new data. However, when I attempted the same fetch in Next.js 13 on the server side with the identical query, it failed. they still fetch stale data. I've attempted numerous fixes, including those you've described, but none have worked.

In a curious twist, adjusting the API version in the config settings (for instance, from '2023-9-10' to '2023-9-11') allowed me to retrieve the new data, albeit only once. After a subsequent data update, I found myself unable to fetch the new data again. I'm beginning to suspect there may be underlying issues with Sanity or another related component. Despite setting 'useCdn' to false, the system behaves as if it's relying on the API CDN, taking cues from the 'apiversion'. It's worth noting this is based on my observations and may not be entirely accurate, but I felt it necessary to share my experience.

Comment: Never faced the stale data problem with sanity until recently, It is very frustrating as I have experimented with multiple projects and each new project i create with sanity fetches the stale data.

Comment: So could you find the solution. I also ran into same issues data is not updating what ever i do on sanity studio. Until I redeploy with even a little changes.